# Matlab figure size changes with I Copy Figure to Visio

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, visio

I print a Matlab figure with 1 inch height and 1 inch width. I click Edit and Copy Figure, then paste it into Visio. There, the figure width and height become 1.65 in. The actual visio figure size, in which this Matlab figure is pasted, is 5x3 inches.

Moreover, the lines and axes thickness are 2 points in Matlab. In Visio, they become 3.31 points. Similarly, marker sizes change.

This is a very serious concern for me, as I can save a lot of time by copying Matlab figure to Visio and then editing.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried exporting to eps or pdf? Failing that, maybe you just have to account for the increase in size by decreasing the size and line width in MATLAB?

Comment: Why you expect Visio to get anything right is certainly beyond me.    In any case,  "editing" a graph is completely the wrong approach.  You should learn how to set any parameter desired via commands or graphics window handles.

Comment: I know a lot about graphics window handles :) and have generated all of my plots through my own code. Here, I needed to copy the figure to have some signals appearing in Visio block diagram. I have even generated block diagrams in Matlab but that wastes time in coordinates calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Under your *Edit--Copy Options*, do you have "Match figure screen size" selected? This may be causing MATLAB to distort the size.

If so, try your *Edit--Copy Figure* operation with this option turned off.

[image: Preferences from MATLAB (c) 2015b]